Auth Class missing in Dropbbox SDK Vers. 6.1.0 - How to handle this
after updating Dropbox SDK API from Version 5.4.6 to 6.1.0 (in Java) Auth-Class isn't recognised.
dropbox-core-sdk:5.4.6' -> dropbox-core-sdk:6.1.0'

I use Auth-Class for PKCE Auth-Flow
for following callings (examples):
Auth.startOAuth2PKCE
Auth.getDbxCredential
Auth.startOAuth2Authentication

I can't find any hint in documentation was dropbox changed or how to handle these changes.
Thanks,
GGK

as documentation says here, You have to add following dependencies:
implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:6.1.0'
implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-android-sdk:6.1.0'

SDK Version 5.4.0 only needs Core-SDK while 6.1.0 needs both of them
